# mysql insert into two tables using auto_increment value from the first table as a foreign key in the second

Tags: php, mysql, myisam

I want to insert into the cart table

```
**orderId** | cartId | cartDate | cartStatus
____________________________________________
1           | 1      | 20120102 | complete
2           | 2      | 20120102 | complete
3           | 3      | 20120102 | complete
4           | 4      | 20120102 | complete
```

using the auto increment value orderId from the order table

```
**orderId** | orderStatus | secret   | sauce
____________________________________________
1           | 7          | 020200202 | bbq
2           | 6          | 020200202 | bbq
3           | 6          | 020200202 | t
4           | 4          | 020200202 | m


INSERT INTO ordertable VALUES(null,7,020200202,bbq)
```

but then using the orderId (which will now be 5)

```
INSERT INTO carttable VALUES(orderId,20120102,complete)
```

However,
this insert must be done as the same query. If I use mysql_last_id (php) there is an opportunity for someone else to insert into the database before my cart insert is executed. Or the connection might timeout. The database is MyISAM (and I can not change this, 3rd party solution).

Thank you,
J

Answer (score 1):

I think your concern about using `mysql_last_id` is unfounded - it will return the last id for the current connection, not the last id globally across all connections.

So unless you have multiple threads sharing the same database connection or you perform another identity insert on the same connection before calling `mysql_last_id`, you should have nothing to worry about.

ETA: You could do this by sending multiple queries at once, like this:

```
INSERT INTO ordertable VALUES(null,7,020200202,bbq);
INSERT INTO carttable VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(),20120102,complete);
```

But if you are using `mysql_query` it usually won't let you send multiple queries in the same call (mostly as a security measure to try to prevent SQL injection).

Comment: if I insert into the order table, then try to insert to the cart and my db connection is gone I will end up with orders without carts. This will break the application. Therefore my insert must be one query.

Comment: @Jamie - not one query, but one transaction.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with MyISAM? I'm inserting offline sales to the maindb where customer might be placing orders on the live site.

Comment: no. myisam doesn't support transactions, and you NEED transactions to make this work reliably.